# Connecting .NET application to MySQL

Tags: mysql, .net, database, vb.net, phpmyadmin

this question has been asked before, but the answers from them didn't help me.

I am not a web developer and I haven't worked with MySQL before. I need online database just for 1 simple task which doesn't matter right now. So, I want to connect my VB.NET application to mySQL.

I am using free hosting https://host-ed.net/ which enables me to create only 1 MySQL database which is enough for me. They provided me with cPanel where I created the mySql database called "**db_clients**". After that, I created 2 users, one for my clients "db_client" and one for me (the owner) "db_owner".

**db_client** Has privilage only to do "SELECT"
**db_owner** Has privilage to do everything with database

Basically, the application that I will give to my clients will just query the online database and check if one column contains true or false. So, from the clients application I want to connect to mySQL database with `Uid=db_client`.

I have downloaded and imported the MySQL connector for .NET. The trouble I am having now is connecting to the actual database remotely. I can't access the database even with "localhost".
I am using phpMyAdmin (tool) to customize the database. Can you please tell me, how, where and what should I search to find the correct value for argument `Server` in connection string.

What I already found is: on phpMyAdmin site, I went to home->selected tab "Variables" -> Typed "hostname" in search bar and it returned **f5.host-ed.me**.
After that, I opened CMD and just pinged that host and got an IP. What should I do next?

This is my current VB.NET Code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

 Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim myConString As String

    myConString = "Server=46.105.118.169; Port=3306; Database=db_clients; Uid=db_client; Pwd=somepass; Charset=latin1;"

    Try
        conn.ConnectionString = myConString
        conn.Open()

        Debug.Print("conn successfully opened")

        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        Select Case ex.Number
            Case 0
                MessageBox.Show("cannot connect to server. Contact admin!")
            Case 1045
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password!")
        End Select
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

This is the result I get when I press the Button:

[image]

*Error: 1042 SQLSTATE: 08S01 (ER_BAD_HOST_ERROR)*

*Message: Can't get hostname for your address*

Do I need to grant an access to specific IP's to access my database?
If the answer is yes, then is there a way around it? I don't want to add IPs manually to a whitelist.

Comment: You may need to whitelist the IP address you're trying to connect from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are You trying to connect to the Remote Database from your local pc? That is not allowed in most of the hosting plans out there. Normally, to access a remote database, you have to write an application on the Server side to manage the actual database access and send requests (for example to an REST-API) to that middleware which then speaks with your database. On server side, your database is reachable directly from localhost as described in the manual of your Host.

Comment: I am trying to make my database public to my clients which are all over the world through my application.

Comment: Yes, I understood that, but you are using a free plan of a hoster. Most hosters do not allow public access to the MySQL databases due to security reasons. If You want the Database to be public, You have to write a middleware to access it.

Comment: http://www.host-ed.me/members/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=14

Comment: Ok, I will now look for hosts that allow remote access.